# What version expresscard slot do I have?

Tags: pci-express

My laptop Elitebook 8640p has a Express card slot. 
But i dont know version of this Pci-e slot. 
Please help me detect version of this PIC-e slot (ver 1.0 or ver 2.0).

This is result of PC-wizard

---

> Bus PCI-Express : Yes
>
> > PCI-Express Information
> >              Number of connectors : 1

```
>> Bus PCI-Express
     Device : 6 Series Chipset Family PCIe Port 1
     Version : 2.0
     Port : 1
     Physical Slot : #0
     Slot Populated : No
     Link Width : max. x1
     Link Speed : 2.5  GB/s

>> Bus PCI-Express
     Device : 6 Series Chipset Family PCIe Port 2
     Version : 2.0
     Port : 2
     Physical Slot : #0
     Slot Populated : No
     Link Width : max. x1
     Link Speed : 2.5  GB/s

>> Bus PCI-Express
     Device : 6 Series Chipset Family PCIe Port 3
     Version : 2.0
     Port : 3
     Physical Slot : #0
     Slot Populated : Yes
     Link Width : x1   (max. x1)
     Link Speed : 2.5  GB/s

>> Bus PCI-Express
     Device : 6 Series Chipset Family PCIe Port 4
     Version : 2.0
     Port : 4
     Physical Slot : #0
     Slot Populated : Yes
     Link Width : x1   (max. x1)
     Link Speed : 2.5  GB/s

>> Bus PCI-Express
     Device : 6 Series Chipset Family PCIe Port 8
     Version : 2.0
     Port : 8
     Physical Slot : #0
     Slot Populated : Yes
     Link Width : x1   (max. x1)
     Link Speed : 5  GB/s
```

---

It has both two difference speed ( 5 Gb/s and 2.5  GB/s ). 
Thanks!
Ps: Sorry about my Eng. It not good!